# Site question: this effects what you can do in the site

Tags: discussion

How do people get reputation on this site? I'd really like to know.

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with anime or manga at all, but I have to know.

Comment: i have flagged this to be migrated to our Meta site where it should be. that said have you bothered to check [the Help Center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help) like the pinned ["What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Since this was migrated to meta, I upv-oted to give poster enough rep to be able to respond there. Otherwise, he would be in a "chicken & egg" situation.  // Well hell, that didn't work. Since this question is actually in anime-meta, an upvote does not gain him any rep. Hello, Chicken! Hello, Egg!

Comment: @RichF actually if what I have seen on SO if you don't have the rep to participate in Meta but you get your question migrated here then you can participate on the migrated question alone (including answers)

Answer (score 7):

Simply said, you post a good questions, and good answers. Other user will upvote your post. You can also suggest an edit to other's post, if it's good enough, the community will approve your edit and you got some rep. Here's the detail

> You gain reputation when:
>
> ```
> question is voted up: +5
> answer is voted up: +10
> answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
> bounty awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
> one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)
> site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)
> ```

You can find more information about how to get (or lose) a reputation here [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

And with more reputation you'll get more [privileges](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)